# How to improve Mysql select speed from big table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have huge 8.5 million lines table , with all wold cities and other data. When i need specific city, like London, it takes a lot of time to do query. I know from what country i want to get data.

```
SELECT * FROM location_cities
WHERE name LIKE 'London%' 
AND iso = 'GB'
```

Is it possible to improve this query speed, when i know country, like GB, FR, US etc.?

Comment: Do you have index on iso ?

Comment: As @Darhazer says, if there's no key on iso, create one if possible.

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good tutorial on SQL indexing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You want to add an index on `location_cities(iso, name)`.  Here is syntax:

```
 create index location_cities_iso_name on location_cities(iso, name);
```

Note this will work best for `like` when the expression does not begin with a wildcard (as in your example).  If you need functionality such as `like '%York'`, then you might need to look into a full text index.

Answer (score 0):

You should try partitioning - in this case by "iso" or other parameters which are often used in your queries. Here is good description how partitioning works and what benefits it can bring:

[Improving Database Performance with Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html)

Comment: I'd only recommend partitioning once all other options have been exhausted, and if you have an experienced MySQL team on hand. Given how basic this question is, I doubt either condition has been met...